# start condition order

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

i already serched google looking for answer and asked this question to my lecturer but he didn't replied me yet and i would like to go on with assigments, so i came to you guys here is a question:

I have this code in flex-lexer:

```
1| "/*"    BEGIN(multi_line_comment);                              
2|         <multi_line_comment>[^*]*
3|         <multi_line_comment>"*"+[^\*\/]*
4|         <multi_line_comment>"*"+"/"       BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

When i will take input like `"/*abc****  * defg*/"`
And my instinct tells me that code in start condition is executed in order `1->2->3->4`, then

after 1 i have `"abc****  * defg*/"` left

after 2 i have `"****  * defg*/"` left

after 3 i have `"  * defg*/"`

after 4 i have `"  * defg"`

*`""` are used to show white spaces, they are not used in input*

However when i compile this code in flex it cut the whole input. So i'm thinking that only way to do this is to execute step 3 two times (`1->2->3->3->4`)

a) So how does start condition work? In what order?

b) Does every step reapeat till it won't fit? If yes then what if after step 3 step 2 starts to fit, does it go back to step 2 or leave the input untouched?

Thanks for answer

Comment: After 4 you have nothing. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: In flex i have nothing, but how? if i only use each statment once there is no way to cut everything

Comment: (F)lex always executes whichever rule matches (or whichever rule matches the longest input, if more than one rule matches). A start condition restricts the set of possible rules.